# Got "failure in processEncodedAnnotation" when mixing guice and scala on Android

Tags: java, android, scala, annotations, guice

My Android project is developed with the **Gradle** build system, and compiles and runs fine. Now I am trying to add Scala to it. Currently, it included these key dependencies:

- Guice
- Scala

I am using the https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin to build my project. I have managed to compile and package the project and deploy on my test Android device. But I got this error on app start:

```
05-22 11:21:13.021: E/AndroidRuntime(21743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
    instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.android.app/com.my.android.app.MainActivity}:
    com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    failure in processEncodedAnnotation
```

The stacktrace is very long and this error has been repeated several times. I think it is the Scala compiler messed up the Annotation that Guice requires. But I am new to Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `sbt clean` before running `sbt android:run`. If you're not using sbt then you may have to clean your project before rebuilding it.

For more information, see [here](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/issues/57).